Input element cannot work on Chrome extension plasmo
all. I'm currently working on a Chrome extension by using plasmo framework. I tried to add a color picker in the popup page, but the color picker does not show properly. The code is quite simple,
<input type="color" value="#ff0000"  />

But there is something wrong with the color picker,

As you may see, the picker does not show completely, there are something missing. It should like this,

But I do not know where goes wrong, could anyone help me solve this issue?
